# Speedup when combining CPU and GPU with OpenCL

Tags: performance, opencl, cpu, gpu

I have an application that uses OpenCL to split a matrix vector multiplication over several devices. I tested the application on a computer with an Intel Xeon CPU and three identical NVIDIA Kepler GPUs. If I use an input size of 2048x2048, then I have a speedup of ~1.4 for the CPU compared to the GPU. Two GPUs have a speedup of ~2 compared to one GPU, but one GPU plus one CPU only has a speedup of ~1.7. If I use three devices, the result looks similar compared to one GPU: Three GPUs have a speedup of ~3, but two GPUs plus one CPU only have a speedup of ~2.4.

So my question is: What can be the reason that the speedup decreases when I replace a GPU with a CPU. The CPU is seperately faster than the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

when you said "I have a speedup of ~1.4 for the CPU compared to the GPU", that means your CPU was actually faster than your GPU by 40%?

I've seen issues like this before when I played with my OpenCL Monte Carlo code (http://mcx.space/mcxcl, and Fig. 3b in [the paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-biomedical-optics/volume-23/issue-01/010504/Scalable-and-massively-parallel-Monte-Carlo-photon-transport-simulations-for/10.1117/1.JBO.23.1.010504.full?SSO=1#ArticleLink) linked in the webpage).

The key is workload balancing - if you divide your job equally to your CPU and GPU, in many cases, your speed may not be significantly faster than CPU alone (adding the additional overhead). But if you give more workload to the more capable hardware, such as 80:20 split between GPU:CPU, you may see an overall increase. Play with that workload split ratio, you may find a balancing point.

Comment: Yes, exactly the CPU was faster than the GPU.

I divide my workload into chunks which are then gradually processed by the devices. A faster device can process more chunks so that a speedup should arise.

Were you able to identify a general problem with the speedup of combining CPU and GPU in your work?

Comment: No, it was not a general issue (unless OpenCL's overhead becomes significant - which happened to me once when I tried to use more than 8 NVIDIA GPUs on one of my rigs containing 12 GPUs). It is a lot easier to deal with this using CUDA, because you can use nvprof to see where was the bottleneck. OpenCL does not have a good profiler.